# Binding a socket: SIGSEGV

Tags: c, sockets

I've declared a pointer to the following struct in my main function

```
struct sockaddr_in* server;
```

I'm using this struct to a function that returns a socket descriptor bound to this struct.

```
int openSocket(char* ip_addr, int port, struct sockaddr_in* server){

    int sockfd, len;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    if(sockfd < 0){
        perror("Failed to open socket: ");
        exit(-1);
    }

    len = sizeof(server);
    bzero(&server, len);
    server->sin_family= AF_INET;
    inet_aton(ip_addr, &server->sin_addr);
    server->sin_port= htons(port);

    if((bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server, len)) < 0){
        perror("Bind failed: ");
        exit(-1);
    }
    return sockfd;

}
```

However when I try to read the individual fields in the struct that was passed into the function, I get a seg fault. That is when I run the following code in my main

```
sockfd = openSocket(vector->ip_addr, vector->port, server);
printf("%s %d\n", inet_ntoa(server->sin_addr), htons(server->sin_port) );
```

The values being passed into the openSocket function are correct.
I get a `segmentation fault`. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You don't  bind a socket to a struct. You bind it to an IP address and port. Please clarify.

Comment: What I mean was that this function returns a socket descriptor after binding it to a struct sockaddr_in

Comment: And you're still wrong. And 'using a struct to a fiunction' is meaningless. You also haven't stated where the SIGSEGV occurs.

Comment: The seg fault occurs when I run the line of code printf.....Isn't that adequately explicit in my question.

Comment: It isn't even implicit, let alone explicit. Also I doubt that it's true. More likely you're getting it in `bind()`, for the reason stated in my answer.

Comment: `struct sockaddr_in* server;` is an uninitialized pointer, have you initialized it somewhere so it points something valid ?

Comment: `len = sizeof(server); bzero(&server, len);` is also obviously wrong.

Comment: I have fixed your title, as you still don't appear to get it.

Answer (score 2):

After I looked through your codes again, I found there are three mistakes.

1. In `main()`, you just declared one pointer to `struct sockaddr_in`, but you didn't assign it, you can define `struct sockaddr_in server` and pass `&server` to `openSocket()`.
2. In openSocket, "server" is declared to pointer, but your statements `len = sizeof(server); bzero(&server, len);` are not correct, this is where your segmentation violation occurs.
3. In `openSocket()`, `bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server, len)` is not correct, you don't need to use `&server`, just use `server`.

So you should change your code as below:

```
len = sizeof(server); ----> len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)
bzero(&server, len);  ----> bzero(server, len);
if((bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server, len)) < 0){ ----->
if((bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)server, len)) < 0){

struct sockaddr_in* server; 
sockfd = openSocket(vector->ip_addr, vector->port, server);
printf("%s %d\n", inet_ntoa(server->sin_addr), htons(server->sin_port) );
---->
struct sockaddr_in server; 
sockfd = openSocket(vector->ip_addr, vector->port, &server);
printf("%s %d\n", inet_ntoa(server.sin_addr), htons(server.sin_port) );
```

Comment: All true but completely ruined by very sloppy formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You just declared "server" as a pointer to `struct sockaddr_in`, but you didn't assign it. You can do it like below:

```
struct sockaddr_in server;
sockfd = openSocket(vector->ip_addr, vector->port, &server);
printf("%s %d\n", inet_ntoa(server.sin_addr), htons(server.sin_port) );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server, len)
```

The problem is here. `server` is already a pointer. You should not take its address.

```
bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)server, len)
```

And, as pointed out by @nos, you need to initialize it somewhere. There's no reason for the static variable to be a pointer. It can just be a `struct sockaddr_in`.

Comment: I tried writing the code with struct sockaddr_in server but the socket doesn't get initialized. What I mean is that if I declare struct sockaddr_in in the main function and then pass it into the openSocket()  function and then later in the code try to check server.sin_addr I get 0.0.0.0

Comment: Correct. You bound to wildcard. You don't get the address until somebody connects.